# Bash: Returns error without sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, kali-linux, command, privileges

I'm running Kali Linux Live, and I was using the system as the root user for a long time before I came across an article online telling you NOT to use root as your default account, and that instead you should create a low-privileged user. I ended up doing just that, and everything was OK, until I tried to run `ifconfig`, to which I received the error: `bash: ifconfig: command not found`.

I tried running `sudo apt-get install ifconfig`, but it returned that `ifconfig` was already the newest version. I was a little confused, so I tried `sudo ifconfig`, since I had to use `sudo` to run `apt-get`. Sure enough, `sudo ifconfig` worked, and any other commands I need to run that return a similar error work with `sudo`.

So my problem is that the programs I need to run are stored (I presume) in the root system when I install them with `sudo apt-get install`, and are therefore unaccessible by non-root users? I'm not sure if that's correct or not. Reading the manual for `sudo`, I know it runs a command as root (or another user in general), but does that mean the "output is executed" in the root's system? If so, what can I do to run commands as a low-privileged user, besides giving them admin privileges?

Thanks for any and all support!

Comment: You probably just need to add `/sbin` to your low-privileged user's `PATH`

Comment: Kali Linux is for penetration testing and is meant to be run as root. That article is referring to workstations and servers where it's best not to run with elevated rights unless it's needed.

Comment: @steeldriver Forgive my noobiness, but how do you do that? Don't you do something like `PATH=/desired/path` when you're first setting up a user?

Comment: @NasirRiley I thought it was so programs that are downloaded don't gain admin access without user permission? Is that security measure not necessary with something like how I use Kali (as a pen testing distro but also just to learn Linux)?

Comment: The error message says you ran the command `config`, not `ifconfig`. Can you test running `ifconfig` as your unprivileged user?

Comment: Well now that I tried what @Peschke said and added `/sbin` to my `PATH`, the command works fine, so I can't show you now, but `.bash_history` shows it was indeed `ifconfig` I typed. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @Anonymous Kali really isn't the right distro to learn Linux on. It's intended for experienced Linux users who want a platform for things like penetration testing. I'd recommend switching to something else -- almost anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can’t find those commands as a non-root user is because they probably aren’t in your PATH. Run an `echo $PATH` to see what directories the shell looks in to find the command you input.

System programs and administrative utilities typically reside in `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`. These programs and utilities can be executed by any user (if they have the appropriate file system permissions set), but usually won’t change anything on the system unless executed as root.

You can add new directories to your PATH with something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

You can run `ifconfig` and `apt-get` as non-root users if you want, but you won’t be able to change any configurations or install packages unless you are root.

Comment: Most likely `/usr/sbin`. It depends on where `ifconfig` exists on your system. You can run `which ifconfig‘ as root to figure that out. As I stated in my answer, adding it to your PATH probably won’t do anything because you need to be root to use those commands.

Comment: Apart from _changing_ things with `ifconfig`, that command can most certainly be used by ordinary users without throwing any errors. Also note that the error message does not mention `ifconfig` but `config`. Unless it's a typo in the question, it may have been a typo on the command line.

Comment: Thanks @Peschke, `ifconfig` now works! And @Kusalananda, I noted `config` error message as well, but the error was copied straight from the terminal and `ifconfig` is in my bash hisory. Nonetheless, I will edit it to be more precise. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Trying again, actually, I opened a new terminal and tried `ifconfig` again and it returned an error message. So I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` to `.bashrc` and it now works.

Comment: Don't put `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` in `.bashrc`. Instead put it in `.profile`. `.bashrc` may be sourced several times, causing your PATH to grow.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I wasn’t able to get to this until now. I didn’t mean that you couldn’t run the command at all, so I clarified that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

They are in `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` **anyone can run them**. However it may or may not be useful to do so. If you don't have the capabilities than most of these commands will not do much. User `root` traditionally has all capabilities. And `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are not normally in a normal users execute search PATH.

`ifconfig` is useful as a normal user, but you won't get all features. e.g. `/sbin/ifconfig` with no arguments, will list all network interfaces.